# Angular: Show Form Elements when select is valid after on change shows all hidden form elements in loop instead only the one which select was changed

Tags: angularjs

i repeat things in ng repeat like so

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="deutscheBankEvent in deutscheBankEvents">
    <div class="schrottler-opened schrottler" title="">
        <span class="presse_ueber" style="font-size:22px;margin-left:10px;font-weight: normal;margin-top:5px">{{deutscheBankEvent.name}}</span>
    </div>
            <!-- data-ng-repeat also possible-->
            <div class="">
                <div class="presse_content">

                    <Div style="color:white">{{deutscheBankEvent.name}}</div>
                    <ul class="liste_k"> 
                      <li ng-repeat="list in deutscheBankEvent.list">
                        {{list}}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

later down the code comes up a form to register to events. the form is hidden until user selects a place and date via select. this is triggered like so:

```
<span ng-show="myForm.locationDate.$valid">
```

my issue  now is: this shows up all hidden form elements when one select is valid.
how can i set the scope to only this one changed?

Comment: What do you mean with "how can i set the scope to only this one changed"? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K6TF5/21/ - just imagine this code rendered in a ng repeat loop.

Comment: => when you change one, the other elements show up too.

Comment: Have you tried to put that sample code inside a `ng-repeat` loop? It works normally: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/K6TF5/22/ Only the input from the select node is shown. Please provide a real example with the exact same problem you're facing.

Comment: this worked, i changed ng-model to checked and ng show too. your fiddle shows exactly the situation i was facing.

Comment: feel free to post it as an answer so i can resolve this issue. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` creates a new scope, changing `ng-show`/`ng-hide` conditions to scope bound properties will work perfectly ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/K6TF5/22/)).